# UI test builder is not tracking UI objects

Tags: c#

I am working on UI automation using VS coded UI test builder, is there a way to track control ids from UI? I am getting co-ordinates for input capture windows for controls which is not useful while rerunning test. eg. Mouse.Click(passwordReset, new Point(408, 398)); I did some research on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286671.aspx and tried to but nothing seemed to map UI controls without co-ordinates. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balagans/archive/2009/12/28/9941582.aspx) should help out a bit. You really want to use SearchProperties which uses the AutomationId (WPF) or Name (WinForms: Name is equivalent of SearchProperty Id and Text is equivalent to SearchProperty Name if my memory serves me right, doesn't make a whole lot of sense). I'm not exactly sure how you do this but we had to go back into our WPF views and add AutomationId's to every control so my coworker could select them when he was setting up automated testing.